# Make nested array to group array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
```

Then I want to make group of 4 elements.
Every iteration, this array must be modified until it get's final face.

Step 1:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
```

Step 2:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],9,10,11,12,13,14];
```

Step 3:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],13,14];
```

Step 3:

```
arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14]];
```

How is this possible?

I tried this:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
var i,j,temparray,chunk = 4;
for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
    temparray = array.slice(i,i+chunk);
    console.log(temparray);
}
```

But I don't know then how to save this chunk into own array and not in the new array.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please provide the code you've already tried and we'd be happy to help you get it working.

Comment: what is with your 4 step approach? now in one (in the accepted answer)? if so, please change the question.

Comment: @NinaScholz every 4 element must be splitted and saved in one array, so left elements are less than 4 and we must save it to use later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lodash probably has better performances than my implementation, but if you are looking to do so with vanilla javascript then you can like this (though many other ways are possible):

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];

var newArr = arr.reduce((acc, val, idx)=>{
 if(idx % 4 === 0){
   acc.push([]);
  }
  acc[acc.length-1].push(val)
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: VanillaJS beats *everything*!

Comment: I was sure lodash would make it faster than my code, but after several checks on jsfiddle I was 3-5 times faster than lodash!!! :)

Comment: VanillaJS only beats everything if you have the skills and experience to write faster and safer code that the author of a well-tested and widely used library.

Answer (score 3):

You could splice the array until the length is smaller than the index of the last insertation.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    i = 0;
    
while (i < array.length) {
    array.splice(i, 0, array.splice(i, 4));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
newArr = arr.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
    if ((index) % 4 === 0) {
        acc.push([item]);
    } else {
        acc[acc.length - 1].push(item);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newArr); // [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10, 11, 12 ], [ 13, 14 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The lodash method [`chunk`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk) will do this for you.

```
result = _.chunk(arr, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];

    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        // Do something if you want with the group
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}
// Split in group of 3 items
var result = chunkArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 3);
// Outputs : [ [1,2,3] , [4,5,6] ,[7,8] ]
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please try to understand the question properly. User is asking to save the array in place and don't want new array.

Answer (score 1):

Just push it to the resulting array:

```
const chunk = 4, result = []
for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
   result.push(array.slice(i,i  + chunk));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be fun too if I add one more solution using `recursive calls`, Happy coding!

Test it here

```js
function split(arr, offset, res){ 
  
  //stop condition (offset exceeds len of array) 
  if(offset>arr.length) 
 return res; 

  //slice 4 elms 
  res.push(arr.slice(offset,offset+4)); 

  //recursion 
  return split(arr, offset+4, res);
  
}
  
var res = split([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 0, []);

console.log(res);
```